# Low fps on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, gaming, fps

I was playing The Elder Scrolls III - Morrowind on my PC, played for few days with no problem but now its fps has dropped very low. Later I noticed that wait icon animations, sticker animations on facebook etc are also gone really slow (They don't lag or get stuck, like slow motion). Even in Chrome loading icon spins slower than before, but browsing speed and stability seems not affected. I don't feel any drop in performance also. What can be the problem here? Need help!!

```
Specs

Windows 8 32bit
1.6 GHz dual core processor
2GB RAM
512MB nVidia geforce 9300 vga with latest drivers for windows 8
```

Comment: Have you recently updated your drivers?  What is the exact fps value?

Comment: Yes, it was drivers by Microsoft which get installed with os. Later I installed drivers from nVidia. Didn't find exact fps value yet but things looks about 50% slower. Game is actually slow motion.

Comment: @LahiruKavinda - The first thing you should try is to roll back the driver version.  Its entirely possible the current Nvidia drivers have a problem with the game in question.  Does your system meet requirements to run the software?

Comment: I'll try rolling back drivers. Yes they meet recommended requirements.

Comment: Thank you all for helping. Rolling back the graphics card drivers solved the problem. Now I re-installed the drivers (same version from my previous download) but now no slow motion and funny things :)